# JFrame not showing up after running

Tags: java, eclipse, jframe

I am working a JFrame calculator, I am not to familiar with so I was following a tutorial, and I've double checked it a couple times. 
It's not working, its not throwing any errors or anything, it will compile and run. Just nothing pops up. 
I am using Eclipse, and it is giving two warnings, 
one about my constructor not being used in my main
that my class says this: The serializable class Gui does not declare a static final serialVersionUID field of type long.

I'm not sure why those would come up, but my code seems to be like the tutorial.

Thank you in advanced.

Ps. excuse the all commons, I just making sure I can looking back at it without having to refer back to the tutorial.

```
// This will make the visuals of the calc

import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class Gui extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

    JPanel[] row = new JPanel[5];
    JButton[] button = new JButton[19];

    String[] buttonString = {"7", "8", "9", "+", // This is a string for the buttons that we will later apply to
        "4", "5", "6", "-", // the the buttons with a loop, instead of 19 lines for each one
        "1", "2", "3", "*",
        ".", "/", "C", "√",
        "-/+", "=", "0"};

    int[] dimW = {300, 45, 100, 90}; // An Array for the different widths of the display and buttons
    int[] dimH = {35, 40}; // An array for the different heights of the display and buttons

    Dimension displayDimension = new Dimension(dimW[0], dimH[0]); // The dims for the display using the first ints of the arrays
    Dimension regularDimension = new Dimension(dimW[1], dimH[1]); // The 
    Dimension rColumnDimension = new Dimension(dimW[2], dimH[1]);
    Dimension zeroButDimension = new Dimension(dimW[3], dimH[1]);

    Boolean[] function = new Boolean[4]; // A boolean array to tell, which operator we are using

    double[] temp = {0, 0}; // A temp array for the calc, might not use when using my stack calc

    JTextArea display = new JTextArea(1, 20); // This is the display where the text will be displayed

    Font font = new Font("Ariel", Font.BOLD, 14);

    Gui() {

        super("Gui");

        setDesign();
        setSize(380, 250); // Set the frame size
        setResizable(false); // Makes so it can't be resized, can mess up layout if it true
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE); // What happens when it closes

        GridLayout grid = new GridLayout(5, 5); // Since we need a grid of 5 by 5 for the buttons this makes the grid
        setLayout(grid);

        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) // Sets values for the function array, might use might not with my clac
        {
            function[i] = false;
        }

        FlowLayout f1 = new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER); // This will only be use to layout row 1
        FlowLayout f2 = new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER, 1, 1); // The ints are used to give a 1 pt gap vert and horiztal

        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) // Intinalizing the Jpanel row's so we can use them
        {
            row[i] = new JPanel();
        }

        row[0].setLayout(f1); // Since we need the first row to have the special layout of f1 we just assign it

        for (int i = 1; i < 5; i++) // Since we already set the first row "Row[0]" to f1, we have to start with row 2 or row[1] for i
        {
            row[i].setLayout(f2);
        }

        // After this all the rows have the correct layout, we can set up the buttons
        // And set the same thing to each button with a loop
        for (int i = 0; i < 19; i++) {

            button[i] = new JButton(); // Creates a new button for each button in the array
            button[i].setText(buttonString[1]); // Sets text on the button with the text from the list, in ButtonString
            button[i].setFont(font); // Makes it nice looking with the fancy font we used in the font line
            button[i].addActionListener(this); // This is what makes the button actually work
        }

        // Buttons done we can move to the display set up
        display.setFont(font); // Set the fancy font to the display too
        display.setEditable(false); // Makes it so no input from the keyboard, will have to change this on final product
        display.setComponentOrientation(ComponentOrientation.RIGHT_TO_LEFT); // Makes it pop in right to left

        // With the fonts and everything intinlized we can start to set the sizes for the compents
        display.setPreferredSize(displayDimension); // Sets the size of the display

        // We can use a loop for the regular buttons, i think all but zero
        for (int i = 0; i < 14; i++) {
            button[i].setPreferredSize(regularDimension); // Sets the size of the regular buttons
        }
        for (int i = 14; i < 18; i++) {
            button[i].setPreferredSize(rColumnDimension); // Sets the size of the right column of buttons, the operrantors 
        }
        button[18].setPreferredSize(zeroButDimension); // Sets the size of the zero button since its bigger

        // Now that we got evrything sized up time to add everything to the panel
        row[0].add(display); // Adds the display to row 1
        add(row[0]); // Adds row 1 to the panel

        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            row[1].add(button[i]); // all the number buttons to the row
        }
        row[1].add(button[14]); // adds the operator button to the row
        add(row[1]); // adds the row

        for (int i = 4; i < 8; i++) {
            row[2].add(button[i]); // all the number buttons to the row
        }
        row[2].add(button[15]); // adds the operator button to the row
        add(row[2]); // adds the row

        for (int i = 8; i < 12; i++) {
            row[3].add(button[i]); // all the number buttons to the row
        }
        row[3].add(button[16]); // adds the operator button to the row
        add(row[3]); // adds the row

        row[4].add(button[18]);
        for (int i = 12; i < 14; i++) {
            row[4].add(button[i]); // all the number buttons to the row
        }
        row[4].add(button[17]); // adds the operator button to the row
        add(row[4]); // adds the row

        setVisible(true); // Makes so you can see it

    }

    // Not sure what this is
    public final void setDesign() {
        try {

            UIManager.setLookAndFeel(
                    "com.sun.java.swing.plaf.nimbus.NimbusLookAndFeel");
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }

    // Will be use to make actionlistener work
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {

    }

    public void main(String[] arguments) {
        Gui c = new Gui();
    }
}
```

Comment: Your `main` method needs to be static.  Are you sure that neither your IDE nor the Java runtime informed you of this?

Comment: beginners to java should really start with a texteditor and the command line...

Comment: @VGR Nope, nothing informed me. It's always the little things. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should really have this in your main method

```
public static void main(String[] args){
Gui c = new Gui();  
c.setVisible(true);
}
```

Comment: Good deal, thanks. Not sure how I over looked the missing static, Thanks Everyone